# PHP require_once not working. Warning error

Tags: php

i am using the PHP function require_once to require a file:

```
<?php require_once 'reviewtickets_history.php?seq='.$_GET["seq"].'&type=history' ;?>
```

but i am getting the error:

```
Warning: require_once(reviewtickets_history.php?seq=34844&type=history) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/public_html/admin/helpdesk/reviewtickets.php on line 316
```

but if i remove my .php file from the URL and enter in the .php page in the brackets above `(reviewtickets_history.php?seq=34844&type=history)` it displays fine

Comment: No you're not requiring a file, you're requiring a url:

Comment: `If "URL include wrappers" are enabled in PHP, you can specify the file to be included using a URL (via HTTP or other supported wrapper - see Supported Protocols and Wrappers for a list of protocols) instead of a local pathname. If the target server interprets the target file as PHP code, variables may be passed to the included file using a URL request string as used with HTTP GET. `

Comment: `This is not strictly speaking the same thing as including the file and having it inherit the parent file's variable scope; the script is actually being run on the remote server and the result is then being included into the local script.`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to link to the docs? `:)`

Comment: What do you exactly want to do ?

Comment: require or include the file. include(); has the same issue too

Comment: @charliejsford See my answer below. You're mixing up filepaths and URLs.

Comment: You realise that you'll simply be including the output generated by that page, not the script that generates it?

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:** To require a file, use local path.

```
require_once '/path/to/reviewtickets_history.php';
```

This will include the full script source, and evaluate the PHP code in your current file. You cannot pass query parameters with this method.

**Option 2:** To require a URL, use a full URL.

```
require_once 'http://mydomain.com/reviewtickets_history.php?myparam=val';
```

This will include the *output* of the script, not the PHP source. You can use query parameters here.

Note that [`allow_url_fopen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) has to be enabled for this second option to work.

Comment: Warning: require_once(/admin/helpdesk/reviewtickets_history.php?seq=34838&type=history) same thing, it works on every other page I'm not sure what the issue could be

Comment: @charliejsford It must be a _FULL_ url. Include `http://` at the beginning, and the domain name.

Comment: allow_url_fopen is not enabled

Comment: @charliejsford Then you can't `include` or `require` a URL. Use `require_once 'reviewtickets_history.php';`. Realize you can't append query parameters when requiring a file like this though.

Comment: @charliejsford Show an example of exactly how you're doing it on another page. You're clearly not doing this exact same thing, or you'd get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

in require_once need to set a path on the server to the file but not a URL. For example you can't pass http://www.example.com/somefile.php but you can do /var/www/folder/somefile.php.

In case then you

```
require_once 'http://mydomain.com/reviewtickets_history.php'
```

it will include the output and not the php functions

Comment: You absolutely can pass a URL, if `allow_url_fopen` is enabled.